# Удалить дубликаты строк в ячейке Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Есть строка подобного формата

```
Данные
"Описание: это описание
Дело: №3424
Описание: это описание"
"Описание: это описание
Дело: №3424
Описание: это  второе описание описание"
```

Данные записаны в двух ячейках, то есть по три строки в ячейке. Необходимо: удалить дубликаты таких строк внутри ячейки + если данные по описанию не совпадают, то взять оба описания через запятую. То есть на выходе должны получить:

> ```
> "Описание: это описание
> Дело: №3424"
> "Описание: это описание, это второе описание описание
> Дело: №3424"
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я вас правильно понял, вы хотите что-то такое. Если просто цикл, то так

```
print(lst)
['Описание: это описание\nДело: №3424\nОписание: это описание', 
 'Описание: это описание\nДело: №3424\nОписание: это  второе описание описание']

def f(x):
    x = x.split("\n")
    x[0] = x[0].replace('Описание: ', '')
    x[2] = x[2].replace('Описание: ', '')
    return 'Описание: ' +('\n'.join(x[:2]) if x[0] == x[2] else '\n'.join([', '.join([x[0],x[2]]),x[1]]))

for x in lst:
    f(x)
Описание: это описание
Дело: №3424
Описание: это описание, это второе описание описание
Дело: №3424
```

Ну, а если в pandas

```
df['A'] = df['A'].apply(f)
```

---

На общий случай выбрасывания дублей

```
def f(x):
    x = x.split("\n")
    return '\n'.join(x[:2]) if x[0] == x[2] else '\n'.join([', '.join([x[0],x[2]]),x[1]])
```

Comment: У меня пишет Описание: ....., Описание: ...... Хотя должно просто Описание: ....., ......

Comment: Переписал функцию

Comment: А можно общую функцию ? А не специально для "Описание" То есть что в целом для любых названий искал дубликаты и удалял

Comment: Старая и была в общем случае, она не понимала про "описание"

Comment: тогда можно старую тоже оставить?

Comment: добавил в ответ

Comment: Что здесь значат 0,1,2 ? На более больших данных выдает `list index out of range`

Comment: Возможно в каких-то случаях нет второго описания? посмотрите `df['A'].str.split('\n').apply(len)` - какие там цифирьки будут. Или так `df['A'].str.split('\n').apply(len).min()`